# Is RC2040M150CH MSP upgradable to 200amps main circuit breaker

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

I have Square-D Main Service Panel RC2040M150CH.
Notice the checkbox on the left for this particular model.

The preinstalled circuit breaker is QOM2150VH for 150 amps; 200amps equivalent is QOM2200VH.
https://stevenengineering.com/Tech_Support/PDFs/45CBMCC.pdf

The Main Service Panel itself is rated as 200amps (see three highlighted places on the photo below). The 150amps preinstalled circuit breaker is what made this MSP RC2040M150CH and not RC2040M200CH.

I think just upgrading main service breaker from QOM2150VH to QOM2200VH will make this MSP completely rated at 200amps, and good to pass inspections?

Thanks.

[image: Main Service Panel rater at 200amps]

Comment: While the main breaker might be upgradeable -- do you know if your service conductors from the utility can handle the extra current?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel some utilities have a "watch and wait" philosophy, they keep an eye on smart meter data to tell when your service lateral/drop needs upgrading,

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, great question! Yep I called our utility company. They said they have no issues with 200amps. Anything higher than 200amps would require "designer work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You're good for that breaker swap

Since your utility is OK with the service upsize and the labeling on your meter-main allows it, putting the QOM2200VH in there instead of the existing QOM2150VH is fine.  You'll need to have the utility pull the meter (they can do this for no-charge during normal working hours) to do this safely, though, and also to make sure that the breaker screws and nuts are torqued to specification on the new breaker (this will require an inch-pound torque wrench).

Comment: ThreePhaseEel, thank you for all your help on this Community. I got a new question related to this topic if you'd like to have a look at that one - https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/149162/neutral-on-main-service-breaker Thanks!