# Neutral on main service breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

Beginning of the story was here - [Is RC2040M150CH MSP upgradable to 200amps main circuit breaker](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147823/is-rc2040m150ch-msp-upgradable-to-200amps-main-circuit-breaker)

So now I got QOM2200VH main circuit breaker (200amps) and ready to install it later this week.

The only question I have is Neutral.

Notice that the current service breaker (QOM2150VH) has a bar which reads "N" on it :

[image: existing breaker]

The new one doesn't have this part (there is no plastic bar which reads "N" on it):

[image]

This a little worries me. Unfortunately I can't disconnect and check in details until the scheduled time with my electric service company to make the disconnect later this week.

Both circuit breakers are two-phase circuit breakers. 
But the existing circuit breaker supposedly has a connection to Neutral!?
And the new circuit breaker doesn't have it!?

Thanks for any leads on this topic.

Comment: Looks to me as though the piece with the 'N' on it clips onto the side of the breaker - and should do the same on your new one.

Comment: hmm. what's the purpose of that plastic clip? thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### What you're seeing is a shield

What you're seeing with the "N" on it appears to be an insulating shield over the neutral crossbar on your panel.  There is no connection from the main breaker to the neutral in a North American electrical panel.

Answer (score 2):

The "N" bit you're seeing in the panel, is not part of the breaker.  It's part of the site the breaker bolts into.

When you pull the old breaker, the bit with the N will stay with the panel.  Don't try to remove it with the breaker.